# How to work with Rails Credentials in Productions Environments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am having difficult to understand how can I work with Rails credentials in Prod environments.

My Use Case. I started a new rails project. It comes with my personal master.key and a credentials.yml.enc that I can edit using the command

```
EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit
```

All is good. All is fine. Now I want to add it to my heroku production app. First I will push my credentials.yml.enc to my github. Then I will set a ENV or a Master Key on my heroku.

My question is.... How can Heroku decrypt the credentials.yml.enc that was created inside my development env (so, it was encrypted used my personal master.key) with their own production key?

Comment: The answer is it can't. The credentials are only able to be decrypted with the key which they were encrypted with - thats the whole point of any two way encryption. You either need to use the same key or better yet use separate credentials for development and production (and keys) so you don't accidentially mess stuff off up on third party services.

Comment: I think where you are going wrong here is the idea that its "your personal key". This is nothing like PGP email encryption for example and the key that you use when generating the credentials file still needs to be shared with other developers. Or if you want to edit the production credentials you locally you need to share the same key between your local machine and heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Heroku section of [this article](https://medium.com/craft-academy/encrypted-credentials-in-ruby-on-rails-9db1f36d8570):

> The easiest way to make encrypted credentials work on Heroku is to get the value stored in `config/master.key`, and use it to set up the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable

This allows Heroku workers to use `Rails.application.credentials` calls just like you are able to do in a console.

The key is to create the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable in Heroku (either through the web interface or the CLI) and set its value to your master key value.

For your specific question:

> How can Heroku decrypt the credentials.yml.enc that was created inside my development env (so, it was encrypted used my personal master.key) with their own production key?

It's the same key. You are going to copy the value of `master.key` to Heroku as the value of the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` variable.